# Azure DevOps WebHook returns 401 Unauthorised when calling Azure Function with Microsoft Identity provider (AAD)

Tags: authentication, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, webhooks

Is there any way how to set the Azure Function Authentication using Microsoft Identity provider (AAD) to allow calls from Azure DevOps Webhooks which is in the same AAD ?

I've tried to set Azure App Service "API permissions" to allow everything from Azure DevOps, but no difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, your post is not a great fit for SO. There aren't enough details to enable us to help you. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: I think you need to create a Service Principal in Azure that you can use from DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

No, the webhook coming from Azure DevOps will be a unauthenticated web request. If you need to make it hard to call, make sure you include a token in de URL and make sure your function verifies the contents of the json payload.

If you need more security, depending in the webhook you want to respond to, might be replaced by a Azure pipelines task calling the Azure functions or could potentially run in Azure pipelines completely instead.

In the pipeline you have way more control over authentication headers and such.